# Adjusting div heights for content

Tags: css, html

I have 3 separate graphical elements; the header, the footer, and the content-background. The content background is repeatable, and my intention is to allow the page to dynamically adjust without breaking any flow of the page. I've tried to achieve this by applying the 'header image' to a div at the top of the page - the 'content-background' to the container (of both the content area and the menu), and finally the 'footer image' at the bottom of the page - outside of the container.

It seems to work well when I have very limited content on the page - however, the moment I put a of content in the content area, it just hangs out over the edge of the images and looks awful, as opposed to repeating the background and nudging the other divs down.

I don't want to introduce overflow:scroll, or anything like such - and I'm desperate to try and avoid JavaScript. I'm sure I've made a flaw somewhere in my thinking, but I'm not too sure where. I have a feeling that I need to do something regarding positioning - and changing the heights of certain divs (container, content are still defined as the base; but whatever I set it at, it either has no effect or causes the page to look bizarre).

Instead of copying-pasting the walls of texts, I've posted the address to a temporary section on my website.

Comment: To long to read, no code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a few issues. Setting a height on `#container` is a problem, and not clearing your floats of your `#content` and `#rightbar` elements is another problem. My belief is that fixing both of those things will give you the result you're expecting.

Comment: Hi - thanks, I'll give it a shot. When I'm not declaring a height on container, the page falls apart. I assume this is because I haven't cleared the floats on content/right bar? Seems to be working fine - thanks! Knew it must be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want your div tags to become bigger as the text gets more and more.

The solution is simple: Use min-width instead of width. it will adjust itself